# get geotiff info like width, height, pixel size with Geoserver REST API

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I want read information for certain layer (not tile) like the ones read from gdalinfo. How can I get these info with the rest api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not, the REST API does not provide this information. You can however get it from a WCS 2.0 DescribeCoverage call, e.g.:

http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/ows?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=DescribeCoverage&coverageId=nurc__mosaic

Comment: It may not be easy to guess what to search from the WCS response. Pixel size is told in the gml:offsetVector lines. The origin you can find from gml:origin and the size of the layer in pixels from gml:GridEnvelope by looking at the low and high values.